# Are there AWS tools to schedule jobs similar to using Quartz Scheduler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, quartz-scheduler

Is there a service available in AWS that can provide this functionality? This would be used to run recurring backend jobs like sending email blasts, monitoring health, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat unspecific.

For monitoring and scheduling tasks you can use [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/). Depending on what you want to do this may be or not be a good fit.

There are tutorials on scheduling [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduledevents-example.html) and [Amazon ECS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html), but it supports lots of other [targets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) as well. For example you could generate a SNS message and SNS could trigger some HTTP(S)/REST-Call doing your processing or you could write a message to SQS and your application polls that queue for getting triggered.